# Run a Saved Query with bq command line utility

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BQ script stored as a "Saved Query". I was wondering if I can execute it using the bq command-line utility. Could not find something relevant in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Saved queries" are only accessible through the console and are not accessible through the API.

An approach that might suit you better would be to use [Scripts and stored procedures](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting-concepts).

In this way you define your SQL routine in a script myprocedure, and use "CALL mydataset.myprocedure()" to run it.

With bq it's then simply:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'CALL mydataset.myprocedure()'
```